# Can i socket message to a known private IP through internet?

Tags: python, sockets, private, public

I cant find an answer as much as i search and i am trying to think that the answer to my question is negative.

But if i know the public and the private ip of a client which has a socket server enabled for receiving messages.

The question is can i send a message to it without having to port forward from the router.

Example code from python socket of sending message:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()

host = "98.87.451.123"
port = 45555

connection = sock.connect((host, port))

message = "5#4#3"
sock.send(message)

data = ""

while len(data) < len(message):
    data += sock.recv(1)

print(data)

sock.close()
```

is it possible to concatenate the public and the private ip on host? Something like this:

`host = "98.87.451.123/192.168.1.10"`

So the router knows where to forward this message?

Comment: Proxying is not directly possible in TCP/UDP/... itself. You can in principle use dark magic such as TCP hole punching, but it is really much simpler to assume a proper network setup in your application and take the time to add port forwarding in your router.

Comment: I know, but if there are several machines on different homes across the globe and you want them to have a socket listening for changes from the server, its not possible to tell to all these people do that.

Comment: If you have a server anyways, they should just open a connection to the server. Only one direction of a TCP connection must be public.

Comment: And how you do that? What do you mean?

Comment: I'm not quite following. The client should naturally be able to connect to the server, by nature of being the client to the server. If it simply does not close this connection, the server can use the standing connection to send messages to the client.

Comment: Yeah i understand what you say, i got confused when i first read your answer. I would like thought the server to communicate to these machines whenever it wants like a notification you are receiving from a chat application in your phone

Answer (score 0):

Nope! Not possible. If this was possible we wouldn't need IPv6.

An IP packet has a destination address in it. It can't have more than one destination address. There are no "care-of" addresses.